# App crashes on AppendCollumn() with a Virtual List Control

Tags: c++, wxwidgets, listcontrol

I am a hobby programmer still learning C++ and wxWidgets.
I use Code::Blocks 20.3, wxWidgets 3.1.4, and MinGW 17.1 on a Windows 10 Pro computer.

I am trying to make a virtual wxListCtrl work in Code::Blocks,
I followed the code in the ListCtrl sample and a simple example in the wxWidgets Discussion Forum.
The sample (1 file) code on both compiles and works.
When I start a new project in Code::Blocks, the GUI APP and MAIN is coded in separate files.
Perhaps I need to do more, but cannot find what it is.
The project compiles with zero errors and warnings, but it shows below error on startup.
I tried moving SetItemCount() above AppendCollumn(), but that did not help.
There is no error when I comment both AppendColumn() out, but then of course the list is empty.

Can someone please help me with what is missing in my code?

Thank you, Ruud

Error:

```
A debugging check in this application has failed
../../src/cpmmon.listctrlcmn.cpp(259):
 assert "Assert Failure" failed in OnGetItemText():
 wxListCtrl::OnGetItemText not supposed to be called
```

GUI code:

```
GUIFrame::GUIFrame( wxWindow* parent, wxWindowID id, const wxString& title, const wxPoint& pos, const wxSize& size, long style ) : wxFrame( parent, id, title, pos, size, style )
{
    this->SetSizeHints( wxDefaultSize, wxDefaultSize );

    wxBoxSizer* bSizer1;
    bSizer1 = new wxBoxSizer( wxVERTICAL );

    m_listCtrl1 = new wxListCtrl( this, wxID_ANY, wxDefaultPosition, wxDefaultSize, wxLC_REPORT|wxLC_VIRTUAL );
    bSizer1->Add( m_listCtrl1, 1, wxALL|wxEXPAND, 10 );

    this->SetSizer( bSizer1 );
    this->Layout();

    // Connect Events
    this->Connect( wxEVT_CLOSE_WINDOW, wxCloseEventHandler( GUIFrame::OnClose ) );
}

GUIFrame::~GUIFrame()
{
    // Disconnect Events
    this->Disconnect( wxEVT_CLOSE_WINDOW, wxCloseEventHandler( GUIFrame::OnClose ) );
}
```

Main Code:

```
#include "VlistMain.h"

const wxChar *SMALL_VIRTUAL_VIEW_ITEMS[][2] =
{
    { wxT("Cat"), wxT("meow") },
    { wxT("Sheep"), wxT("baaah") }
};

VlistFrame::VlistFrame(wxFrame *frame) : GUIFrame(frame)
{
    m_listCtrl1->AppendColumn("Animal");
    m_listCtrl1->AppendColumn("Sound");
    m_listCtrl1->SetItemCount(WXSIZEOF(SMALL_VIRTUAL_VIEW_ITEMS));
}

wxString VlistFrame::OnGetItemText(long item, long column) const
{
    return SMALL_VIRTUAL_VIEW_ITEMS[item][column];
}
```

Event table:

```
wxBEGIN_EVENT_TABLE(MyListCtrl, wxListCtrl)
    EVT_LIST_ITEM_SELECTED(wxAny, MyListCtrl::OnSelected)
wxEND_EVENT_TABLE()
```

Comment: `m_listCtrl1` private or protected? Also prefer using `bind` rather than `connect`. In addition, `VlistFrame::VlistFrame(wxFrame *frame) : GUIFrame(frame)` this approach does not make much sense.

Comment: m_ListCtrl1 was protected, but there is no difference when it is public. BTW, This how the listctrl sample and the code in the forum actually work. The approach you mentioned "modular" may not make sense to you, but it has been working for me on everything I created sofar

Comment: BTW; When the app has started, the virtual ListCtrl is showing including the column headers. The error states that OnGetItemText() should not have been called (which is the mystery to me).

Comment: @Ruud, what is the backtrace at the time of the assert?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's a second answer that uses wxFormbuilder's subclass feature.  The advantage of this approach is that it will let you set up event handlers with wxFormbuilder.  First we'll need to have a slightly different declaration for the constructor for the derived class

```
class MyListCtrl:public wxListCtrl
{
public:
    MyListCtrl(wxWindow *parent,
               wxWindowID id,
               const wxPoint& pos = wxDefaultPosition,
               const wxSize& size = wxDefaultSize,
               long style = wxLC_VIRTUAL | wxLC_REPORT);
    virtual wxString OnGetItemText(long item, long column) const wxOVERRIDE;
};
```

This add's more parameters to the constructor so that it will be compatible with the code generated by wxFormbuilder.  As in the other answer, this should be placed in a new header file that is added to the project.

Next in a code file, add the body for the constructor

```
MyListCtrl::MyListCtrl(wxWindow *parent, wxWindowID id, const wxPoint& pos,
                       const wxSize& size, long style)
           :wxListCtrl(parent, id, pos, size,
                       wxLC_VIRTUAL | wxLC_REPORT, wxDefaultValidator,
                       "MyListCtrl")
{

}
```

Note that this forces the the subclass to have the style `wxLC_VIRTUAL | wxLC_REPORT` and will ignore any style entered in wxFormbuilder.  So if you want to change the style, you should change it in the code above.

Alternately you could change `wxLC_VIRTUAL | wxLC_REPORT` to `style`.  Then the style options entered in wxFormbuilder will be used.  But then it's up to you to make sure those options always include wxLC_REPORT and wxLC_VIRTUAL  and do not contain any other options that are incompatible with those two.

Next, in wxFormbuilder, add a list control to your form and on the object properties tab, set the subclass options to

```
name: MyListCtrl
header: MyLstCtrl.h
```

[image]

(you can leave the forward_declare option checked or unchecked - it doesn't make any difference).

Now you can add any event handlers for your list control just like with any other widget:

[image]

Comment: Brilliant. Thank you very very much. I currently have 2 virtual listctrl's sharing one MyListCtrl class working, based on the size of the 2 respective source vectors. This is not optimal, because there is no guarantee that the sizes are always different in the actual app I am creating. I hope there is a way to identify the ID of the listctrl that calls OnGetItemText().

Answer (score 2):

To use a virtual list control, you need to derive a class from wxListCtrl and override the OnGetItemText method.  For example:

```
class MyListCtrl:public wxListCtrl
{
public:
    MyListCtrl(wxWindow *parent, wxWindowID id);
    virtual wxString OnGetItemText (long item, long column) const wxOVERRIDE;
};

MyListCtrl::MyListCtrl(wxWindow *parent, wxWindowID id)
           :wxListCtrl(parent, id, wxDefaultPosition, wxDefaultSize,
                       wxLC_VIRTUAL | wxLC_REPORT, wxDefaultValidator,
                       "MyListCtrl")
{

}

wxString MyListCtrl::OnGetItemText(long item, long column) const
{
    return SMALL_VIRTUAL_VIEW_ITEMS[item][column];
}
```

You can also override [OnGetItemColumnImage](https://docs.wxwidgets.org/trunk/classwx_list_ctrl.html#ac2650c225e81512af8dcff22ab50a9dc) and [OnGetItemAttr](https://docs.wxwidgets.org/trunk/classwx_list_ctrl.html#a3f3dc83dc001e747eda4702d2a4f494a) to further customize your control.

---

Since it looks like you're using wxFormbuilder, you can do this using the Custom Control widget. To do this, first you need to add a new header file to your project named MyListCtrl.h (or whatever you want to call it).  The contents of the new header should look something like this:

```
#ifndef MYLISTCTRL_H_INCLUDED
#define MYLISTCTRL_H_INCLUDED

#include <wx/listctrl.h>

class MyListCtrl:public wxListCtrl
{
public:
    MyListCtrl(wxWindow *parent, wxWindowID id);
    virtual wxString OnGetItemText (long item, long column) const wxOVERRIDE;
};

#endif // MYLISTCTRL_H_INCLUDED
```

Once you have the header for your control, you can use the "CustomControl" widget. It's the second to last item on the Additional tab:

[image]

On the properties tab, you'll need to set the following items

```
name:          m_listCtrl1
declaration:   MyListCtrl* m_listCtrl1;
construction:  m_listCtrl1 = new MyListCtrl(m_panel1, wxID_ANY);
include:       #include "MyListCtrl.h"
```

like so:

[image]

You can the provide the code for the `MyListCtrl::MyListCtrl` constructor and `MyListCtrl::OnGetItemText` in the same file as your devived frame class.  Or if you want maintain one class per file, you can also put it in a new cpp file.  Obviously you need to add "#include "MyListCtrl.h" at the top of which ever file you use to put the code for those methods in.

---

To handle events using event tables, you would need to add declarations for the event handling methods and the `wxDECLARE_EVENT_TABLE` macro to the class declaration.

```
class MyListCtrl:public wxListCtrl
{
public:
    MyListCtrl(wxWindow *parent, wxWindowID id);
    virtual wxString OnGetItemText (long item, long column) const wxOVERRIDE;

protected:
    void OnItemSelected(wxListEvent& event);
    // Add all other event handler method declarations here
private:
    wxDECLARE_EVENT_TABLE();
};
```

Then in the file with the code you would have something like:

```
wxBEGIN_EVENT_TABLE(MyListCtrl, wxListCtrl)
    EVT_LIST_ITEM_SELECTED(wxID_ANY, MyListCtrl::OnItemSelected)
    /* Add all other event macros here */
wxEND_EVENT_TABLE()


void MyListCtrl::OnItemSelected(wxListEvent& event)
{
    // do something here
}

// write all other event handlers here.
```

---

On a personal note, I really don't like event tables, so I would use dynamic event binding instead.  To do this, the declaration for the class should look something like this:

```
class MyListCtrl:public wxListCtrl
{
public:
    MyListCtrl(wxWindow *parent, wxWindowID id);
    virtual wxString OnGetItemText (long item, long column) const wxOVERRIDE;

protected:
    void OnItemSelected(wxListEvent& event);
    // declare all other event handlers here.
};
```

Then the code for the constructor should look something like this:

```
MyListCtrl::MyListCtrl(wxWindow *parent, wxWindowID id)
           :wxListCtrl(parent, id, wxDefaultPosition, wxDefaultSize,
                       wxLC_VIRTUAL | wxLC_REPORT, wxDefaultValidator,
                       "MyListCtrl")
{
    Bind(wxEVT_LIST_ITEM_SELECTED, &MyListCtrl::OnItemSelected, this);
    // Add any other needed Bind statements here
}
```

Comment: Great. Thank you. I completely overlooked the class in the ListCtrl sample. It is working now. Although; the Custom Control does not have eg. an OnSelected event. I added DECLARE_EVENT_TABLE() in the MyListCtrl header and the event-table (as added in my question) in the cpp. A build error that says: F:\SDKs\wx314\include\wx\event.h|4288|error: ISO C++ does not permit 'wxListCtrl::sm_eventTable' to be defined as 'MyListCtrl::sm_eventTable' [-fpermissive]|. I moved both to the Main header and cpp, but there it also gives build errors. How can I add the wxListCtrl events that I need?

Comment: Do I need to create a new class for each virtual listCtrl I need?

Comment: I have OnSelected() working albeit not with an event table (what I preferred). But finding all selected items crashed the app. I used the well known while ((m_lItemIndex = m_listCtrl1->GetNextItem(m_lItemIndex, wxLIST_NEXT_ALL, wxLIST_STATE_SELECTED)) != wxNOT_FOUND) loop within the function OnSelected(). Is this not allowed with virtual listctrl? What might be the alternative?

Comment: I've edited the answer to show how to handle events.  I'll post another answer using wxFormbuilder's subclass feature that will let you use wxListCtrl's events instead.

Comment: For the second question, you'll either need to create a subclass for each virtual list you want, or you'll need some way to pass data to the list control that can be used by the OnGetItemText method.